need help to merge two halves of a 3d object
I have two halves of an object i scanned with a 3d scanner and have imported the .obj files with texture.  I need to merge the two halves together to make one smooth object and remove the overlapping mesh.  Forgive me if this is a simple solution but i am not able to find a good tutorial on this after searching for days. 

It looks like a regular sphere: can't you create a new sphere and apply the material to it?

these are two halfs of a 3d scan.  how can i save the material off each half and combine it into one material to use?

You can UV map both parts, bake the material, combine the two in photo editing software. But that's for another question (which I'm sure is here somewhere!).
